# Paperclip: How to resize an image only if it is big enough?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip

I use Paperclip to resize pictures like this:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :asset, :styles => { :thumb => "80x80#", 
                                         :medium => "1280x800>" }, ...
```

When the size of the original picture is `32x32`:

1. The resulting `medium` picture is of the same size (i.e. `32x32`), but the file is a bit different and the picture looks a bit changed. Why is that ?
2. The resulting `thumb` size is `80x80` (it looks stretched to fit this size). 
   How could I avoid resizing the picture when it's too small. Assume that original picture's dimensions are in the `width` and `height` variables.

Comment: Hello? What did you come up with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(1) Is probably because Paperclip is decoding a JPEG and then writing/encoding a new JPEG. JPEG is a lossy format so each encoding degrades the image. You could use the [`convert_options`](http://rdoc.info/gems/paperclip/2.3.15/Paperclip/ClassMethods#has_attached_file-instance_method) to adjust the [JPEG quality](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality) but you'll probably have to accept some degradation in your JPEGs.

(2) is because Paperclip is doing as it's told. Paperclip uses ImageMagick to do the heavy lifting and the style dimensions are just [ImageMagick geometry strings](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry) with [one modification](http://rdoc.info/gems/paperclip/2.3.15/Paperclip/ClassMethods#has_attached_file-instance_method):

> Paperclip also adds the “#” option (e.g. “50x50#”), which will resize the image to fit maximally inside the dimensions and then crop the rest off (weighted at the center).

Your `:thumb` style uses "#" so you're telling Paperclip that you want a 80x80 image even if the image has to be scaled and cropped to get there. You can drop the "#" from the dimensions string and, if desired or appropriate, add one of the [the other modifiers](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I do want the "#" behavior, and I wonder whether it's possible to "hack" paperclip so that the image will be resized only if image's dimension exceeds a specified dimension (I think it a reasonable requirement).

Comment: @Misha: Are you looking for the `<` or `>` modifier? See [Image Geometry](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry). AFAIK you're stuck with the ImageMagick modifiers (plus `#`) unless you want to patch Paperclip itself.

Comment: I want the `#` modifier, but I don't want to to enlarge images. I checked all the modifiers in the link that you gave, and none of them matches my needs. More specifically, if image dimensions are `width x height`, then: **(1)** If `width <= 80 && height <= 80`, thumbnail's size should stay `width x height`. **(2)** Otherwise, `#` behavior should apply, i.e. thumbnail's size should be `80x80`.

Comment: @Misha: Then I think you'll have to hack Paperclip.

Comment: Did you manage to hack it? I have a `medium` style of `768x` and would like this to only apply if the image is larger than 7680px wide. If not, use original size to avoid getting all stretched and blurred.